# Put the checkbox value onto a label

Tags: jquery, checkbox, label

I want to make a seat reservation program. I want, when you click on a checkbox, it puts the value of the checkbox onto a label.

```
 <table>
             <tr>
            <td><label> Naam </label></td>
           <td> <div> <?php echo form_input($username); ?></div></td>
           <td><label> Naam </label></td>
           <td> <div> <?php echo form_input($username2); ?></div></td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>e-mail </label></td>
            <td><div> <?php echo form_input($email); ?></div></td>
            <td><label>e-mail </label></td>
            <td><div> <?php echo form_input($email2); ?></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label> gsm-nummer </label></td>
            <td><div> <?php echo form_input ($gsmnummer); ?> </div></td>
            <td><label> gsm-nummer </label></td>
            <td><div> <?php echo form_input ($gsmnummer2); ?> </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>zitplaats</label></td>
            <td><div id="seatDiv"> <?php echo form_label('seat'); ?> </div></td>
               <td><label>zitplaats</label></td>
            <td><div id="seatDiv2"> <?php echo form_label('seat'); ?> </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
       <td> <?php echo form_submit(array('name'=> 'verzend','value' => 'verzend')); ?> </td>
       <td> <?php echo form_submit(array('name'=> 'plaats','value' => 'Bevestig plaats')); ?> </td>
      <?php echo form_close(); ?>

     <?php echo form_open('user/register3'); ?>
             <td><?php echo form_submit(array('name'=> 'Voeg_toe','value' => 'voeg toe'));  ?> </td>
       </tr>
    </table>

     <?php echo form_close(); ?>
 <table>
  <tr>
        <th width="23" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z01" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/> </th>
        <th width="23" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z02" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/></th>
        <th width="6" scope="col">&nbsp; </th>
        <th width="6" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
        <th width="23" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z03" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/> </th>
        <th width="23" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z04" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/></th>
        <th width="23" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z05" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/></th>
        <th width="23" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z06" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/></th>
        <th width="23" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z07" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/></th>
        <th width="6" scope="col">&nbsp; </th>
        <th width="11" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
        <th width="26" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z08" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/> </th>
        <th width="20" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z09" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/></th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
        <th width="23" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z10" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/> </th>
        <th width="23" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z11" align="center"/></th>
        <th width="6" scope="col">&nbsp; </th>
        <th width="6" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
        <th width="23" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z12" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/> </th>
        <th width="23" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z13" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/></th>
        <th width="23" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z14" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/></th>
        <th width="23" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z15" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/></th>
        <th width="23" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z16" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/></th>
        <th width="6" scope="col">&nbsp; </th>
        <th width="6" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
        <th width="26" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z17" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/> </th>
        <th width="20" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z18" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/></th>
</tr>
<tr>
        <th width="23" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z19" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/> </th>
        <th width="23" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z20" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/></th>
        <th width="6" scope="col">&nbsp; </th>
        <th width="6" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
        <th width="23" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z21" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/> </th>
        <th width="23" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z22" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/></th>
        <th width="23" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z23" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/></th>
        <th width="23" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z24" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/></th>
        <th width="23" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z25" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/></th>
        <th width="6" scope="col">&nbsp; </th>
        <th width="6" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
        <th width="26" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z26" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/> </th>
        <th width="20" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z27" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/></th>
</tr>
<tr>
         <th width="23" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z28" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/> </th>
         <th width="23" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z29" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/></th>
         <th width="6" scope="col">&nbsp; </th>
         <th width="6" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
         <th width="23" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z30" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/> </th>
         <th width="23" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z31" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/></th>
         <th width="23" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z32" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/></th>
         <th width="23" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z33" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/></th>
         <th width="23" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z34" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/></th>
         <th width="6" scope="col">&nbsp; </th>
         <th width="6" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
         <th width="26" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z35" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/> </th>
         <th width="20" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z36" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/></th>
</tr>
<tr>
        <th width="23" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z37" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/> </th>
        <th width="23" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z38" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/></th>
        <th width="6" scope="col">&nbsp; </th>
        <th width="6" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
        <th width="23" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z39" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/> </th>
        <th width="23" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z40" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/></th>
        <th width="23" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z41" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/></th>
        <th width="23" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z42" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/></th>
        <th width="23" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z43" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/></th>
        <th width="6" scope="col">&nbsp; </th>
        <th width="6" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
        <th width="26" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z44" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/> </th>
        <th width="20" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z45" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/></th>
</tr>
<tr>
        <th width="23" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z46" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/> </th>
        <th width="23" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z47" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/></th>
        <th width="6" scope="col">&nbsp; </th>
        <th width="6" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
        <th width="23" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z48" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/> </th>
        <th width="23" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z49" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/></th>
        <th width="23" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z50" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/></th>
        <th width="23" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z51" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/></th>
        <th width="23" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z52" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/></th>
         <th width="6" scope="col">&nbsp; </th>
        <th width="6" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
        <th width="26" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z53" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/> </th>
        <th width="20" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z54" align="center" onchange="javascript:process()"/></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The procces function is a function i written before,that you only can check one checkbox.

Comment: jQuery acts on the client's side, not the server. With this in mind could you post the rendered HTML (view source) rather than the php/server side script?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this in your onchange method :

```
$("#seatDiv").html($(this).val());
```

having :

```
<tr>
        <td><label>seat</label></td>

         <td><div id="seatDiv"> <?php echo form_label('seat'); ?> </div></td>
</tr>
```

in your html.

using JQuery, you can then easily add this behavior on all seat checkboxes.

To have this done automatically on every checkbox, just put this in global script of the page :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$("input[name=check]").change(function() {
    $("#seatDiv").html($(this).val());
}
```

}

Comment: But I have also a onchange method proccess on my checkboxes. Should this work?<th width="23" scope="col">&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z01" align="center" onchange="javascript:process(),place()"/> </th>

Comment: actually what you can done is to add some global script to manage the new behavior. Check additional code in my answer

Comment: Ok, but know if I have 2 people who want to make a reservation. I copied the function two times but changed #seatDiv to #seatDiv2. When the project runs, and i select the second seat it changes the first seat also to te second.

Answer (score 0):

```
<label id="SeatNumber">    
<input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Z08" align="center" onchange="javascript:process(this)"/>
$("SeatNumber").html(this.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name=checkbox]').click(function(){
$('#labelId').text($(this).val());

});
```